# shell script - printing result to a file and command prompt simultaneously

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a way to simultaneously print a result to command prompt and to a file?

for example:

```
    echo a >test.log
```

the output "a " must be written both to test.log file and command prompt simultaneously.

Comment: By `command prompt`, you probably mean `terminal`.  The command prompt is the string displayed by the shell on the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

The command `tee` does this, most Linux distro's have this installed by default.

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

Usage:

```
echo abc | tee test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use command tee

> echo a |tee test.log

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee` which reads from standard input and writes to standard output and files.

Comment: Your answer is not at all different from the one given by sudo_O earlier.

Comment: If you want i can delete my POST.